# Как вынести выражения из под скобок после чего решить его?

Tags: python, строки

n = "√(9-5)-√(4+5)" Мне надо, чтобы алгоритм выносил 9-5 и 4+5,после чего решал эти два выражения и добавлял их в список.
Пример:

```
root = []

n = "√(9-5)-√(4+5)"

z = "9-5"

n = eval(z)

n = 4

root.append(n)
```

И точно также с 4+5

Comment: Ну опять же регулярками, они будут чуть сложнее, чем в предыдущем вопросе про скобки, но будет тоже самое примерно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

алгоритм как в прошлой вашей задаче, только ищем не только цифры, но и знаки

а затем полученную строку выполняем - это самый быстрый способ решения выражения иначе надо писать отдельно его парсер

```
import re

n = "√(9-5)-√(4+5) + 15"

res = [eval(text) for text in re.findall(r'\(([0-9-+]*)\)', n)]

print(res)
```

правда `eval` использовать надо на свой страх и риск :)

Comment: А на каком ресурсе ты нашел все значения re.findball?

Comment: т.е. `все значения`? в википедии есть статья "регулярные выражения", там же внизу список ссылок, например "Шпаргалка по регулярным выражениям" (https://www.exlab.net/tools/sheets/regexp.html), а также в сети есть сайты где вы можете потестировать свои регулярные выражения (тоже полезным очень бывает). Я сам их пока не очень знаю, т.е. что-то базовое сделать могу, но регулярки - это отдельный язык, позволяющий реализовывать зачастую очень сложную логику

Answer (score 0):

если смущает использование функции `eval()`, то можно решить так:

```
from re import findall

n = "√(9-5)-√(4+5) + 15"
d = {
    '+': lambda x,y: x+y,
    '-': lambda x,y: x-y
    }
res = [d[o](int(x), int(y)) for x, o, y in findall(r'\((\d+)(\D+)(\d+)\)', n)]
print(res)  # [4, 9]
```